# Why am I getting an error when adding a filter to my application?

Tags: angularjs

My Angular application has code like this to add a service:

```
stApp.factory('entityService', ['$http', '$q', '$resource', function (
                          $http, $q, $resource) {
```

Now I just added a filter like this:

```
stApp.filter('truncate', function () {
    return function (value, wordwise, max, tail) {
        if (!value) return '';
```

When I debug I find that it reads in the line stApp.filter.

However when I run my code:

```
{{modal.data.text | trunacate:true:15:' ...'}}
```

I get a message saying:

```
Error: Unknown provider: trunacateFilterProvider <- trunacateFilter
at Error (<anonymous>)
at http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:2714:19
at Object.getService [as get] (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:2840:39)
at http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:2719:45
at Object.getService [as get] (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:2840:39)
at $get (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:10451:24)
at filter (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:6590:14)
at _filterChain (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:6581:41)
at statements (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:6557:25)
at parser (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:6484:13)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I think my code is okay and can't understand why I get this message.

Comment: You have typo here: `trunacate`

Answer (score 3):

Spelled incorrectly.

```
{{modal.data.text | trunacate:true:15:' ...'}}
```

should be

```
{{modal.data.text | truncate:true:15:' ...'}}
```